# File structure in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to understand the file structure in Netbeans.

For example: I want to create a new class. I do so by right clicking the navigation bar, and get prompted to name my new class. A warning appears with the words "It is highly recommended that you do not place Java classes in the default package"

So,

1. What does go in the "default package"?
2. What goes in the Test Packages and Test Libraries folders?
3. If I have some text files or some such thing for my program to read, where should they go?

I'm taking some online courses on Java, but these sort of nuances aren't covered in the classes. I want to start doing it right, right now, so I don't have to untangle all of my files later on down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refresh your understanding by reading the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

The default package is a package that gets created for your project. It's OK to organize your files under the default package, but if your work is somewhat serious, you're going to want to place them under a named (and therefore non-default) package, like `com.myorganization.myproject` as per the tutorial. NetBeans will also allow you to refactor (rename) an existing package. Left click, hit F2 and supply a new name.

Test packages and libraries used to test your project go in the Test Packages and Test Libraries directories. It sounds like you're a ways off from testing with frameworks like JUnit, however, so you needn't concern yourself with those things just yet.

If you have arbitrary data files, you can really put them wherever you can find them later. If you're working with Android, for example, you'd have a `/res` directory just under your project root with resources like images, icons, data files, etc. You can create your own `resources` directory, or you can be lazy and dump them directly in the project root. Wherever you put them, you have to make sure you call them correctly using absolute or relative paths.

If you're using online courses, especially if you're paying for them, use the resources they provide, like live tutors or their forums. This kind of fundamental/tutorial help is a bit below the threshold for Stack Overflow.